# Matrix to triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

Is there a simple way to represent a triangular matrix as a triangle, like Pascal's triangle?

I've seen [various](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xbge.png) [solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/pascals-triangle-in-tikz) that display [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), but I think that there should be a straight-forward command to display any general triangular matrix in a similar way from a LaTeX or from a SageMath input matrix.

As an example was requested, let me paste here dalibor.zeleny's solution from one of the links:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n in {0,...,4} {
  \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
    \node at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {${\n \choose \k}$};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces: [image]

Comment: Are, please, you able to get a code? If your answer it is yes, could you add here? Thank you for your collaboration.

Comment: So, what you mean is that you would like to have an input such as `a \\ a & b \\ a & b & c \\ ` etc. and this should render as a triangular matrix?

Comment: Here is another solution that you might find useful, but only for smaller triangles: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142132/224487 .

For larger triangles, I think the scripts provided in dalibor.zeleny's question would be more appropriate. Link to their question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17522/224487

Comment: How would such a matrix look like when exported from SageMath? Just like a comma separated list, or differently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there are loads of solutions for Pascal's triangles on this site already. However, I understand your question rather that you want to have something where you can input an arbitrary list of entries and these will then arrange according to a triangular matrix automatically.

The following would do just this (still based in Ti*k*Z):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{tmline}
\newcounter{tmposn}
\newcommand{\tmatrix}[2][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
        \setcounter{tmline}{1}
        \setcounter{tmposn}{0}
        \foreach \k in {#2} {
            \stepcounter{tmposn}
            \node[anchor=base] at (\thetmposn-\thetmline/2,-\thetmline) {${\k}$};
            \ifnum\thetmposn=\thetmline\stepcounter{tmline}\setcounter{tmposn}{0}\fi
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

    \tmatrix{1,2,3,4,5,6}

    \bigskip

    \tmatrix[y=.75cm, x=1.25cm]{1,2,3,4,5,6,a,b,2x+4y,\sqrt{2},\frac{3}{4},\sum^n_{i=0}{x^i},\textrm{out},\textrm{of},\textrm{ideas}}

\end{document}
```

[image]